# WUG not importing Windows 2008 SP2 SNMP data

Tags: snmp, windows-server-2008

We are trying to add a device (2008 SP2) to WUG v14.1.  The server has the SNMP information setup correctly, the SNMP service is running, and the firewall is disabled.  Adding the server to WUG works just fine however no additional information is pulled into WUG.  We really want WUG to be able to monitor the trap information off the server but it appears that after WUG queries the server nothing comes back and no information is populated about the server.

Does anyone know what steps we should take next to try and get the server to return information to WUG?

Thanks.

Comment: I determined that it was actually a content management switch interfering with the nodes talking back to WUG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that it was actually a content management switch interfering with the nodes talking back to WUG.  By moving to a new content mgt switch it will actually pass the pings and the SNMP data back through it to WUG, vs a non-helpful auto response just sending back off the switch.